# db connection with jsp

Tags: java, database, connection

How to connect to Oracle with a Java program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to go through [JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html).

You should never really have anything other than presentation logic in JSP. I am worried that thinking of connecting to Database from JSP is a *bad idea*. Use Servlets with JSP. Keep JDBC connectivity in servlet and presentation logic in JSP.

As long as solving your problem stands, you can just embed Java code in JSP as mentioned here [Establishing a Connection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html). For Oracle, use URL like

```
jdbc:oracle:thin://[host][:port]/SID
```

See this [worked example](http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/Oracle-JDBC-Driver-Connection-URL.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:xyz/ abc@(descrip 
tion=(address_list=(address=(protocol=tcp) (host=servername or ip) 
(port=1521))) (source_route=yes)(connect_data=(sid=ora)))");
```

Answer (score 0):

I should point out that doing database transaction inside a JSP is not a good idea.  It is generally thought to be better to do the request argument processing and database heavy lifting in a pure Java servlet within your webapp, attach the results as request attributes, and then use the request dispatcher to 'forward' to or 'include' the JSP.

One problem with doing database stuff in the JSP itself is that it is difficult to report problems properly.  For instance the JSP will most likely commit the response right at the beginning, making it impossible to change the response status code and/or headers.  The net result could be the delivery of a truncated page with the wrong status code.